# Help with these isomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be an affine algebraic set and $f\in K[X]$ where $K[X]$ is the coordinate ring of $X$. Suppose $I(X)=\langle G_1,\ldots,G_r\rangle$ and $W=Z(G_1,\ldots,G_r,FT_{n+1}-1)$, where $G_1,\ldots,G_r\in k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$.

The image of $F\in k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$ in the quotient $K[X]$ is $f$, i.e, $f=F+I(X)$.

I'm trying to prove these isomorphisms:

$$k[W]\cong \frac{k[T_1,\ldots,T_n,T_{n+1}]}{\langle G_1,\ldots,G_r,FT_{n+1}-1\rangle}\cong \frac{k[X][T_{n+1}]}{\langle fT_{n+1}-1\rangle}\cong k[X][1/f].$$

I couldn't prove it (I tried a lot), if someone could help me with some of these isomorphisms it would be very helpful to me and I would be very grateful.

I really need help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Where do you still have problem?

Comment: Dear @EhsanM.Kermani I still don't completely understand why $(k[T_1,\cdots,T_n]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r)) [T_{n+1}] \cong k[T_1,\cdots,T_n][T_{n+1}]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r)$ and why the isomorphism is preserved if you take the quotient from both sides by the ideal $(fT_{n+1}-1)$. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @user75086, I added the detailed explanation. Usually, you should be able to fill all the gaps when you see the guidelines. If you see you can't, this indicates you've missed some preliminary materials. As an advice, going through them helps a lot. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Well, break it down into some small pieces as follows: $k[X]=k[T_1,\cdots,T_n]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r),$ so

$$k[X][T_{n+1}]=(k[T_1,\cdots,T_n]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r)) [T_{n+1}] \cong k[T_1,\cdots,T_n][T_{n+1}]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r)$$

which is in fact

$$k[X][T_{n+1}]\cong k[T_1,\cdots,T_n,T_{n+1}]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r).$$

Then show that the isomorphism is preserved if you take the quotient from both sides by the ideal $(fT_{n+1}-1).$

For the final isomorphism, let $R=k[X],$ define the ring morphism $R[T_{n+1}] \to R[1/f]$ by sending $T_{n+1} \mapsto 1/f,$ then show that it is surjective and its kernel is the ideal $(fT_{n+1}-1).$

**Added:**

- Building the first isomorphism.

To prove $R[X]/I[X] \cong (R/I)[X]$ for $R=k[T_1.\cdots,T_n]$ and $I=(G_1,\cdots,G_r)$ define $g: R[X] \to (R/I)[X]$ by sending a polynomial with coefficient in $R$ to the polynomial with coefficient in $R/I.$ That is, first consider the projection morphism $\pi: R \to R/I$ sending $r \mapsto r+I$ and then

$$g(r_nX^n+\cdots+r_1X+r_0)=(r_n+I)X^n\cdots+(r_1+I)X+(r_0+I)$$

It is easy to show that $g$ is a surjective ring homomorphism. Basically $g$ is constructed from $\pi$ which is a surjective ring homomorphism. Now, in order to use the [first isomorphism theorem for rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem_2) we should show that the kernel of $g$ is $I[X],$ which is clear since the kernel of $\pi$ is $I$ and $g$ was constructed from $\pi$ by adding a variable $X,$ so the kernel of $g$ is $I[X],$ or if $g(r_nX^n+\cdots+r_1X+r_0)=0$ means that $(r_n+I)X^n\cdots+(r_1+I)X+(r_0+I)=0$ and $0$ in the ring $(R/I)[X]$ is $I[X]$ because a polynomial is equivalent to zero (always zero) if and only if all of its coefficients are zero, that is, $r_i+I$ is zero in $R/I$ for $1 \leq i \leq n,$ and the zero element in $R/I$ is just $I,$ so $r_i+I=I$ implying $r_i \in I$ for all $i.$

**Remark**: As I explained in my last comment, since $I=(G,\cdots,G_r)$ is an ideal of $k[T_1,\cdots,T_n]$ then $I[T_{n+1}]$ will be an ideal in $k[T_1,\cdots,T_n,T_{n+1}],$ but *we still can write* $(G,\cdots,G_r)$ instead of $(G,\cdots,G_r)[T_{n+1}]$ when we say consider $(G,\cdots,G_r)$ now as an ideal in $k[T_1,\cdots,T_n,T_{n+1}]$ with no harm.

- Why taking quotient of $(fT_{n+1}-1)$ is preserving the isomorphism?

Back to our notation, we showed that

$$k[T_1,\cdots,T_n,T_{n+1}]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r) \cong (k[T_1,\cdots,T_n]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r))[T_{n+1}]$$

and since $k[X]=k[T_1,\cdots,T_n]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r)$ we then have

$$\varphi: k[T_1,\cdots,T_n,T_{n+1}]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r) \cong k[X][T_{n+1}]$$

say the isomorphism map is called $\varphi.$

To prove

$$k[T_1,\cdots,T_n,T_{n+1}]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r,FT_{n+1}-1) \cong k[X][T_{n+1}]/(fT_{n+1}-1)$$

again define a map

$$p: k[T_1,\cdots,T_n,T_{n+1}]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r) \to k[X][T_{n+1}]/(fT_{n+1}-1)$$

by sending an element in $s \in k[T_1,\cdots,T_n,T_{n+1}]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r)$ to $\varphi (s) \in k[X][T_{n+1}]$ and the sending it to $\pi (\varphi (s)) \in k[X][T_{n+1}]/(fT_{n+1}-1)$ where

$$\pi: k[X][T_{n+1}] \to k[X][T_{n+1}]/(fT_{n+1}-1)$$

is the natural projection.

Since $p=\pi \circ \varphi$ then is a ring homomorphism and since $\pi$ is surjective and $\varphi$ is an isomorphism then their composition $\pi \circ \varphi$ is surjective, so $p$ is a surjective ring homomorphism. Again to use the first isomorphism theorem for rings, we should show that the kernel is $(FT_{n+1}-1)$ which is clear since $p(s)=0$ for some $s \in k[T_1,\cdots,T_n,T_{n+1}]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r)$ is meaning that $\pi (\varphi(s))=0$ which means $\varphi(s) \in \ker(\pi)=(fT_{n+1}-1).$ So $\varphi(s)=(fT_{n+1}-1)t$ for some $t \in k[X][T_{n+1}]$ by definition of an ideal. Since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism so its inverse is also an isomorphism then $s=\varphi^{-1}((fT_{n+1}-1)t)=\varphi^{-1}(fT_{n+1}-1) \varphi^{-1}(t).$ The way $\varphi$ was constructed shows that $\varphi^{-1}((fT_{n+1}-1))=FT_{n+1}-1$ because $F \mapsto f$ via the projection $k[T_1,\cdots,T_n] \to k[X].$ Therefore, $s \in (FT_{n+1}-1)$ and $\ker p \subset  (FT_{n+1}-1).$ Obviously $(FT_{n+1}-1) \subset \ker p,$ hence the equality, so we're done.

For the last isomorphism in the question follow the same approach and the last paragraph before "Added."

Comment: Dear Ehsan, thank you very much for your answer. I couldn't prove that $(k[T_1,\cdots,T_n]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r)) [T_{n+1}] \cong k[T_1,\cdots,T_n][T_{n+1}]/(G_1,\cdots,G_r)$, can you give me some hints how to proceed?

Comment: @user75086, Basically, you want to prove that $(R/I)[x] \cong R[x]/I.$ Note that you can write any polynomial with coefficient in $R/I,$ as follow: $(a_n+I)x^n+\cdots+(a_1+I)x+(a_0+I)=(a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0)+I.$

Comment: Then they are equal, not only isomorphic?

Comment: @user75086, No, I wouldn't say that. They're basically two different sets. Also note that, when we write $R/I$ it means $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and so $R[x]/J$ means $J$ is an ideal of $R[x],$ so if you don't want to use abuse of notation, since you might get confused, it's better to write the above isomorphism as $(R/I)[x] \cong R[x]/I[x]$ which would be the same as $R[x]/I$ but now this $I$ is different from the previous $I$ in $R/I.$

Comment: Dear Ehsan, thank you very much for the details, I didn't understand just the four last lines: "The way $\varphi$ was constructed shows that $\varphi^{-1}((fT_{n+1}-1))=FT_{n+1}-1$ because $F \mapsto f$ via the projection $k[T_1,\cdots,T_n] \to k[X].$ Therefore, $s \in (FT_{n+1}-1)$ and $\ker p \subset  (FT_{n+1}-1).$ Obviously $(FT_{n+1}-1) \subset \ker p,$ hence the equality, so we're done." because you didn't show the isomorphism $\varphi$ explicitly.

Comment: Dear @user75086, initial we defined $g$ and by using the first isomorphism theorem for rings, we constructed $\varphi.$ This is the explicit construction. Perhaps, you should review the theorem once more to shed more lights on this. The fact that $\varphi^{-1}(fT_{n+1}-1)=FT_{n+1}-1$ is directly coming from the construction. Also, since $s$ is a multiple of $FT_{n+1}-1$ i.e. $s=(FT_{n+1}-1) \times \varphi^{-1}(t),$ therefore, $s$ is in the ideal generated by $FT_{n+1}-1$ i.e. $s \in (FT_{n+1}-1).$ And because, $p(s)=0$ implied $s \in (FT_{n+1}-1)$ shows that $\ker p \subset (FT_{n+1}-1)$

Comment: ... and now if you take an element in the ideal $(FT_{n+1}-1)$ say $(FT_{n+1}-1) \times w,$ *because of the construction* $\varphi((FT_{n+1}-1) \times w)=\varphi(FT_{n+1}-1)\varphi(w)=0 \times \varphi(w),$ so the ideal $(FT_{n+1}-1) \subset \ker p.$

Comment: Dear Ehsan how can be possible $\ker p=(FT_{n+1}-1)$? since $(FT_{n+1}-1)$ is not a subset of the the domain of $p$.

Comment: @user75086, this seems very confusing for you. Ok, lets reverse the construction. With the same technique show that the map $k[T_1,\cdots,T_{n+1}]/(FT_{n+1}-1) \to k[X][T_{n+1}]/(fT_{n+1}-1)$ is a surjective ring homomorphism with kernel the ideal $(G_1,\cdots,G_r).$ Can you prove this now?

Comment: No, it's not necessary, I think I understood what you did. However the Kernel in my calculations was $\ker p=\frac{(G_1,\ldots,G_r,FT_{n+1}-1)}{(G_1,\ldots,G_r)}$ and I used the third isomorphism theorem to have the desired result.

Comment: Yes, I'm glad you understood it :) Btw the second approach (my last comment) is somewhat easier but less illuminating.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, without you I couldn't understand these isomorphisms! Btw could you improve the last paragraph for others? I think the $\ker p$ doesn't seem quite right. thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I don't have time these days, but I'll explain more in a few days.