# Prove that $R\left[x\right]/I\left[x\right]\cong\left(R/I\right)\left[x\right]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal of a ring $R$, define $I[x]$ to be the set of all polynomials whose coefficients are in $I$. Prove that $R\left[x\right]/I\left[x\right]\cong\left(R/I\right)\left[x\right]$

Help me some hints

Comment: I have proved it here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592097/help-with-these-isomorphisms/592128#592128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to consider the map :

$$\phi :R[X] \rightarrow (R/I)[X]$$
such that :$\phi(a_0+a_1X^2+...+a_nX^n)=\bar{a_0}+...+\bar{a_n}X^n$ then it is clear that $\phi$ is surjective and $Ker(\phi)=I[X]$ so we have : $$R[X]/I[X]\cong (R/I)[X].$$